# unexpected behaviour in if statement in php code

Tags: php, javascript

The console in a html file calling the php code shows the following results when the php code is executed:

> php processing: debug 3: TEST IF: in IF
>
> php processing: debug 4: false

However, I'd expect the the first console result to be `php processing: debug 3: TEST IF: in ELSE`. E.g., it seems that according to the console the wrong (if) part of the if-else statement is executed and I don't understand why (for this very simple code)???

Any suggestions?

Php code:

```
//TEST CODE
if($productselected_form[0] == true)
{
    $response_array['debug3'] = 'TEST IF: in IF';
}
else
{
    $response_array['debug3'] = 'TEST IF: in ELSE';
}
$response_array['debug4'] = $productselected_form[0];

//send the response back
echo json_encode($response_array);
//END TEST CODE
```

Javascript code (console.log in ajax call to php code):

```
console.log("php processing: debug 3: "+msg.debug3);
console.log("php processing: debug 4: "+msg.debug4);
```

Comment: so what's the value of `$productselected_form[0]`, or should we just guess?

Comment: What does `$productselected_form` contain?

Comment: do a `var_dump($productselected_form[0])` to see EXACTLY what you're testing against. Since you're using the simple `==` equality test, PHP is free to typecast/convert as needed, and MANY things will test equal to `true`.

Comment: as the post says, `$productselected_form[0]` contains `false`.

Comment: @MarcB, look at the debug4 line.  It's serializing as false.  Does anything besides false serialize to false in json_encode?

Comment: $productselected_form[0] = false (as monitored by the second console line in the javascript code)

Comment: @akonsu: Or rather contains something that doesn't convert to `true`.

Comment: @user2543182: Does the log really show `'php processing: debug 3: TEST IF:'`?  Or did you mis-type the question?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: (copy paste from console in webbrowser:) php processing: debug 3: TEST IF: in IF

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: The literal string `'false'`?

Comment: @Neal: prior to the code shown here: $productselected_form = $_POST['productvalid']; $_POST['productvalid'] contains an array of (false or true) values

Comment: @user2543182: You can't post booleans, they are actually strings.  So, you're doing `'false' == true`, which is `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're comparing a String value to a boolean which will always evaluate to true. You should compare String to String like so

```
//TEST CODE
if($productselected_form[0] == 'true')
```

Comment: a lot of haters out there today it seems

Comment: Hm.... compare your answer to @RocketHazmat's one. Sure you strike the right point, but this is not really an answer that gives any explanation or anything.

Comment: Yes, I should have added the fact he's comparing a String value to a boolean which will always evaluate to true

Comment: thanks for all comments and suggestions. I had indeed used 'false' instead of false ;-(

Answer (score 2):

Your `$productselected_form[0]` is probably a string, not a boolean.  When using `==`, PHP converts the types so that it can compare them.

I'm guessing you have `'false'`, not `false`.  When converting to boolean, the following strings are `false`:

- '0'
- '' (empty string)

Anything else is `true`.  So when you do `$productselected_form[0] == true`, you are actually doing `'false' == true`, which evaluates to `true`.

---

To convert `'false'` to `false` you can do something like this:

```
$productselected_form[0] = ($productselected_form[0] === 'true');
```